# Install MongoDB in macOS Ventura 13.5 via homebrow get an 'LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)' error

Tags: mongodb, macos, installation, homebrew

I am installing the mongoDB from offical tutorial:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x
When at the final step, by running "brew install mongodb-community@6.0", I get the error (from ruby??)
[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0G8p.png)
It says:
Installing mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)

My homebrew version:
[here is the version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSIX7.png)
My macOS version: 13.5.

I have tried: reinstall ruby, delet all homebrew/core and tap them; untap and tap mongodb/brew, the error still occur. Also, when install  mongodb-community@5.0, I got the same error.